# How to make list header and footer not click able?

Tags: java, android

I have a list with footer and header. I added onLongClick to delete item from list. When I press long on header it remove first item from list. When I click on last item or footer the app will crash- item out of range.

> **Can I make footer and header not clickable? or how should i count item in adapter? or is there some other way to baypass it?**
>
> > Removing items:

```
list.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                int position, long id) {
            // Delete Item from List

            ShoppingItem simpleItem = null;

            if (shoppingListApplication.getAdapter().getCount() > 0) {
                simpleItem = (ShoppingItem) shoppingListApplication
                        .getAdapter().getItem(position);
                removeShoppingItem(simpleItem,
                        shoppingListApplication.getAdapter());

            }
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to use [addHeaderView (View v, Object data, boolean isSelectable)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView%28android.view.View,%20java.lang.Object,%20boolean%29) and [addFooterView (View v, Object data, boolean isSelectable)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addFooterView%28android.view.View,%20java.lang.Object,%20boolean%29) to make Header and Footer of ListView not clickable.

Just pass `false` in place of `isSelectable` for Header and Footer.

Pseudo code,

```
listview.addHeaderView(header_view, null, false);
listview.addFooterView(footer_view, null, false);
```

Comment: I did that but it is not working like it should. (result is the same as I add listview.addHeaderView(header_view) ).

Answer (score 2):

For Seperate Context menu in `HeaderView` and `FooterView` of `ListView`.

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();

    if (((AdapterContextMenuInfo)menuInfo).position == 1) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.foo1, menu);    // HEADER MENU
        return;
    }
    else if(((AdapterContextMenuInfo)menuInfo).position == listView.getAdapter().getCount() + 1) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.foo2, menu);    // FOOTER MENU
        return;
    }
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.foo3, menu);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you add list header on your ListView, the index of your first item in the adapter is 1.
If you didn't add header, the index of your first item in the adapter is 0.

Comment: Ok but when I click on 1 item in list I remove 1 item in list and when I click on header I remove 1 item in list. It should work different.

Comment: Please post your program in here, so then I can answer. I guess you remove item at index of 0 in a ListView with a header.

Comment: You should use logcat to check which position you clicked. When you clicked your ListView header, the 3rd argument of OnItemLongClick (position) will be 0. The item in the adapter with position 0 is not the ListHeader, but it is an item. So try to decrement position with 1 before you use position.